# Add a large uiview as a subview without overflowing

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a uiview that i need to add a subview to, the subview's width
is twice the width of the parent view, and i don't want this suview to overflow,
i need the overflown area to be hided, how can i achieve that?

Comment: Can you try to post a concise code fragment of what you have currently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
view.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

For your superview - the view which has the subview, call message

```
 [*SUPERVIEW* setClipsToBounds:YES];
```